# Error 53 occurs when connecting to local file share

Tags: windows-7, networking, file-sharing

I have Windows 7 Pro PC and am trying to connect to a file share located on a Server 2008 machine. I was previously able to connect to the file share on this computer, but recently I started getting error 53 when trying to map the drive. The other computers on my network are able to connect to the server. I am able to ping the server using IP address and NetBIOS name. If I try `net view` or any other `net` command (using the IP or NetBIOS name), I receive error 53. I believe it may have been caused in part by the installation of NETGEAR ReadyNAS Remote. I uninstalled the program, but I am still unable to connect to the share. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you reboot in 'Safe Mode with Networking', does it behave the same way?

Comment: Yes in safe mode with networking enabled I am still unable to connect to the file share nor am I able to us the net view command without being returned an error reading "network path not found"

Comment: Still having the same issue can anyone help with this.